# PHP export to CSV dies after 10000 records

Tags: php, csv, export

I want to export my result set, of about 26000 records, into csv.

It's not working when it goes past the 10000 range.

Even after I have changed the `max_execution_time` to 60 in php.ini.

My code looks like this:

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
print "$header\n$output";
```

Can anyone give me a heads up to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: maybe its memory limit, see in error log, try to set ini to see if this is the problem with ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');
set_time_limit(0);

Comment: it may work longer than 60 seconds? can you show your export code?

Comment: @Haim Evgi: 1024M isn't a solution, that would consume 1Gb of memory on each request ... the solution would be to query the database with a range limit ...

Comment: i agree with u , i mean its only to check if this is the issue

Comment: Where does $output come from?

Comment: Is the file large? Have you tried chunking the file? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595485/php-file-download/

Answer (score 1):

Why storing everything into $output? Output each line as you read it from the database, no need to use up memory to store everything just for output.

And avoid fetchAll and similar methods... output each row...