# How can I password protect a binary file download?

Tags: php, password-protection

I would like to create a very simple php protector on an arbitrary binary file, where the user enters a password and the file is downloaded to their computer, but they must enter the password each time they want to download.

In the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4116144/391161) to the question [Easy way to password-protect php page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115719/easy-way-to-password-protect-php-page), the line `include("secure.html");` seems to require that the file has to be displayable ascii, renderable by the browser.

Is there a way to protect a binary file, say `foo.bin` with the same level of simplicity (and similar limited degree of security)?

Comment: I recommend using PHPass for password hashing in PHP, It's easy and very safe. http://www.openwall.com/phpass/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the folder to where your file is stored to deny all and then using readfile you should be able to access it.

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];

        if($user == "admin"
        && $pass == "admin")
        {
            $file = 'path/to/file';

            if (file_exists($file)) {
                header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
                header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                header('Expires: 0');
                header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
                header('Pragma: public');
                header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
                ob_clean();
                flush();
                readfile($file);
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
?>

<form method="POST" action="">
    User <input type="TEXT" name="user"></input>
    Pass <input type="TEXT" name="pass"></input>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: I thought about using Apache with HTTP Auth, but modern browsers tend to cache the credentials, and I want to force the user to type the password each time they log in.

Comment: Couldn't you use a header like: header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate)

Comment: Unclear whether all the major browsers will actually obey that server directive. Also, I'm running PHP out of cgi-bin, which might further limit the use of such headers.

Comment: I believe you can replace the include in the example you had in your question with a header to the path of your file. See edit in my answer.

Comment: Will this work if the path is not web-accessible though (so people can't just download it using the path)?

Comment: Okay, I guess I needed to combine your answer with this one. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5641534/391161

Comment: If you edit your answer to include those three lines, it will match with my working implementation.

Comment: Gotta love the good old copy+paste from the php docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php#example-2374

Comment: Edited answer with tested script for what you need. Just make sure your directory is set to deny all.