# How do I create a form whose action URL matches the current URL (and preserves GET parameter)?

Tags: php, post, get

In particular, I have a form with some parameters to `POST` which submits to itself, but I would like to preserve the `GET` parameters when the form is submitted.

For example, if the original URL is `http://mydomain.com/download.php?fname=foobar.bin`, I want that to be the URL when I make the `POST`. But the `foobar.bin` part of the URL might change.

Here is a minimum working example

```
<?php

$pass = $_POST['pass'];

$filename = $_GET['p'];

$file = "../../cgi-secret/$filename";

if($pass == "foobar")
{
    header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    // The PDF source is in original.pdf
    readfile($file);
}
if(isset($_POST))
{?>
    <form method="POST" action="download.php?p=$file">
        Password <input type="password" name="pass"></input>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get File" ></input>
        </form>
<?}
?>
```

On this line, I want to post to the current URL, whatever that happens to be

```
    <form method="POST" action="download.php?p=$filename">
```

To give some context, I am trying to modify the answer to my question 
[How can I password protect a binary file download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137408/how-can-i-password-protect-a-binary-file-download) so that I can pass the filename as a `GET` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`?  Short of looping the existing `$_GET` array when you render the form it's probably the most straightforward approach.

An example:

```
<form method="POST" 
      action="download.php?p=$filename&<?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>">
```

In the case that you don't have access to `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`, you could use:

```
    <form method="POST" 
          action="download.php?p=$filename&<?php foreach($_GET as $key => $val) echo $key.'='.urlencode($val).'&'; ?>">
```

Comment: I have not seen that, I will try that.

Comment: I just tried a simple page with `echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];` and it is printing nothing. 
Does this variable exist if PHP is executing under cgi-bin?

Comment: See revised answer - you should consider pre-calculating that query string rather than generate mid-template.

Comment: (I think, ) Using an empty action attribute submits to the current URI, query string included. `<form action="" method="post">`

Comment: (I think) You're right, but I think @merlin2011 is wanting to add to the existing query string, not just post to the same one.

Comment: I want to preserve the original query string, but just POST more information, so Michel's solution may work for me. I can't test right it right now because I'm at work behind a proxy, but I'll try it when I get home.