# Headers used to download file php

Tags: php, header, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php, file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595485/php-file-download)

I have files that are not in the web root that I need to make available for download. So I have a script that uses the below to download the file requested. The problem is, I everyfile downloaded is corrupt? The files are ok because if I use FTP to download, they open. Here are the headers passed:

```
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 200 OK");
        header("Cache-Control: public"); // needed for i.e.
        header("Content-Type: " . $download[0]['mime']);
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" .$download_file);
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
        header("Content-Length:".filesize($attachment_location));

        readfile($attachment_location);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is an example of headers used for that:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

```
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
```

Comment: Thank you, this works a treat, thought I needed to set mime type to content type