# How to download .sql.bz2 file using php

Tags: php

I'm trying to download `.sql.bz2` file using php. But i am unable to do it.

My code is downloading file but file not opening. I want file location to be hidden from user.

I am using following code:

```
$folderroot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$fileurl = $folderroot."/dbname.sql.bz2";   
$downloadfilename = generaterandomcharacters(10).".sql.bz2";          
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.sql.bz2');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
readfile($fileurl);
```

Comment: is it a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13513443/383834

Comment: Your question is not clear. The is file downloading but still want to download it?

Comment: When uploading file via form than file is not located in `DOCUMENT_ROOT` (check via FTP, there is no new files). Check `$_FILES` array for `tmp_name` to get path of file.

Comment: File is downloading but its not actual file, its not opening

Comment: Open the file in notepad, you will see notices/error or output thas was set before downloading the file. Thats why its corrupt then

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code and it worked for me.

So I'd say that the value your giving to **$fileurl** is probably incorrect.

Try this :

```
$folderroot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$fileurl = $folderroot."/dbname.sql.bz2";   
if ( file_exists($fileurl) ) {
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.sql.bz2');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    readfile($fileurl);
}
else
{
 echo 'cannot find file : ' . $fileurl;
}
```

Comment: Download is working but file download is not correct

Comment: what do you mean by "file download is not correct" ? Do you mean that the browser doen't know how to open it and just saves it ? That's is normal with the **Content-Type: application/octet-stream**. Is it something else ? Please clarify.

Comment: I am getting following error: archive is damaged, if i download file directly its working fine.

Comment: try to add header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');, please look into http://stackoverflow.com/a/13513443/383834

Comment: it works ok for me with chrome and firefox on ubuntu. What app are you using to open the file ? Also do try @Stasik 's suggestion, although it  works for me without.

Comment: What app are you using to open it ?  
How did you create your bz2 archive ?  
Can you open the file if you recover it via other means that your download page ?

Comment: This is the url: http://64.64.25.126/facebook/clients/amin/waver/list.php you can try downloading jan 03 backup

Comment: I just get a page which says "nofile" for jan 03 and all the other links.

Comment: i think you tried some other date try January, 03, 2015

Comment: Tried again. Same error. Tried **3rd, January, 2015 Download backup** resulted again in white page saying "nofile". Other date links behave the same way.

Comment: Yep it works now. I can download the archive and open it. But file extracted is binary. Is it supposed to ?

Comment: ok it should be sql file its not working on my end what tool you use to open file ?

Comment: Just the default archive app in ubuntu 14.04 : Archive Manager

Comment: The question is how do you generate your archive file ?

Comment: These files are posted from another server backup generated from standard linux command

Comment: ok which command (with options) do you use for the backup and which command (and options) do you use for the transfer ?