# How to make a file downloadable

Tags: php, download

Am trying to add file download to my site for audio video and pdf files
Am using the php header() function but instead of downloading the output file, it keeps on downloading the php page instead. here is my code.

```
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; 
            Content-type: audio/mpeg; 
            filename=thefile.type');
```

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595485/php-file-download?rq=1

Comment: Why dont you just link or redirect to the file? `header("location: thefile.type");`

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the contents of the file out, e.g.

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; 
   Content-type: audio/mpeg; 
   filename=thefile.type');
echo file_get_contents("thefile.type");
```

Comment: `echo file_get_contents...` !

Comment: Whoops. Completely forgot. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

This works pretty well

```
    if (file_exists("audio/thefile.type"))
    {
         if (FALSE!== ($handler = fopen('thefile.type', 'r')))
            {
             header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
             header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
             header('Content-Disposition: attachment; 
                     filename=audio/thefile.type');
             header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: chunked'); //changed to chunked
             header('Expires: 0');
             header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
             header('Pragma: public');
             //header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('thefile.type')); //Remove

             //Send the content in chunks
             while(false !== ($chunk = fread($handler,4096)))
                  {
                    echo $chunk;
                  }
             }
             exit;
    }
    else{

           echo "<h1>Content error</h1><p>The file does not exist!</p>";
         }
```