# Force download excel file using PHPExcel

Tags: php, http, http-headers, phpexcel

I'm using following headers to output excel sheet generated through PHPExcel:

```
// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Instead gibberish text is sent to the browser:

```
PK������&DG�D�X��������[Content_Types].xml��MN�0���"�%nY ��vAa  �(0����ؖg�w{&i�@�nbE�{��y��d۸l
    m�����X�(���)���F��;@1_�����c)j�x/%��E��y�
```

Could anyone help me with proper headers to force download an excel file? Many thanks.

**Edit 1:**

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Still not working

Comment: possible duplicate of [php, file download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595485/php-file-download)

Answer (score 7):

Wrong Content Type and Filetype won't help:

`application/vnd.ms-excel` is for `.xls` files created with the `Excel5` Writer

`application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` is used for `.xlsx` files created with the `Excel2007` Writer

But if you're seeing that `gibberish` (which is actually the xlsx file itself) in the browser, then the chances are that you're echoing or printing something else to the browser as well, even if it's only a whitespace character like a space, tab or newline before you send those headers

Comment: "Read" (open in browser) or "Download" (application/octet-stream)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Mark. But I still get gibberish response.

Comment: Use "view source" and look for any characters such as spaces or newlines at the beginning of that `gibberish`

Comment: I was having the exactly same issue ... The problem was I put a blank line at the beginning of my PHP file, and I guess the browser try to display this line and thus, the excel file. Removing the line make it work.

Answer (score 5):

Clean the output

```
ob_end_clean();
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem stole my lifetime! Kill it like this:

```
ob_get_clean();
$objWriter->save('php://output');
ob_end_flush();
```